# Pandas Search for minimum value in Column A, then grab the value in Column B of the same row

Tags: python, pandas

I have a DataFrame object:

```
fruit   quantity
apple   500
pear    400
orange  300
```

I wish to search for the smallest value in column `quantity`, then get the corresponding value in column `fruit`.

Currently my solution is:

`df.sort_values(by='quantity',ascending=True)['fruit'][0]` I expect this to return `'orange'`.

Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

Try this to get the index of the minimum value of a `pandas.Series` column with `.idxmin()` method and use `.loc` to get the corresponding value in column `fruit`

```
df.loc[df.quantity.idxmin(), 'fruit']
```

Answer (score 1):

If want first `quantity` of first minimal value of `quantity` use [`DataFrame.set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) for index and then [`Series.idxmin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.idxmin.html):

```
out = df.set_index('fruit')['quantity'].idxmin()
print (out)
orange
```

If possible multiple minimal values use [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
out = df.loc[df['quantity'].eq(df['quantity'].min()), 'fruit'].tolist()
print (out)
['orange']
```